# Django foreign key on many to many field

Tags: django, django-models

A company can have many job categories. A job has to be related to that company's job categories. How can I do it correctly?

So  a job is a foreign key on Company's category choices.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    job_categories = models.ManyToManyField(JobCategory,blank=False)


class Job(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Also it is recommended to pass model class as `string` (aka lazy relationship) to avoid any circular dependencies: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)  `job_categories = models.ManyToManyField('your_app_name.JobCategory', blank=False)`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz It wont be an issue. On my other apps I use `from oherappname.models import modelclass as whatever`

Answer (score 2):

This code might translates what you want : two nested 1-N relation

```
class Company(models.Model):
    (...)  # No need for a field here

class JobCategory(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='categories'))

class Job(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(JobCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='jobs')
```

You can take advantage of reverse relations :

```
company = Company.object.get(...)
related_categories = company.categories.all()
for category in related_categories:
   jobs = category.jobs.all()
   print(jobs)
```